# Table rows summarize by Month in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

I've the following Oracle table;

| Site(VARCHAR2) | Product | Order Date(Date) | Quantity(Number) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 3/5/2021 12:20:15 PM | 100 |
| B | Y | 3/5/2021 12:20:15 PM | 200 |
| A | X | 3/6/2021 12:20:15 PM | 500 |
| A | Z | 3/6/2021 12:20:15 PM | 400 |

I've a requirement to generate a summary similar to the following from the above table;

Here, the summary is generated for a particular product to indicate the sales spread during last six months;

[image]

How can this be achieved using Oracle SQL?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Nuwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL the columns you select must be known when writing the query. You don't know though, what will be the last six months at the time the query will be run. What this means is: you cannot select columns called July to December, because the query may get run in May. You can, however, select columns you call "current month", "last month", etc.

```
select
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + interval '1' month
           then quantity
      end) as "current month",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '1' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
           then quantity
      end) as "last month",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '2' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '1' month
           then quantity
      end) as "current month minus 2",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '3' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '2' month
           then quantity
      end) as "current month minus 3",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '4' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '3' month
           then quantity
      end) as "current month minus 4",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '5' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '4' month
           then quantity
      end) as "current month minus 5",
  sum(case when order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - interval '5' month
           and order_date < order_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + interval '1' month
           then quantity
      end) as total
from mytable
group by site
order by site;
```

If you want to restrict this to one product, add a `WHERE` clause.